# AutoCloseable metric wrapper

Tags: java

Is it semantically correct to use AutoClosable for a class that wraps a block of code and produces a time metric? From what I understand there is no resource here, which is a concern according to http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000157.html

```
class Metric implements AutoCloseable {
  private final Logger logger;
  private int startTime;
  public Metric(Logger logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  static Metric createStarted(Logger logger) {
     Metric metric = new Metric();
     metric.startTimer();
     return metric;
  }

  public startTimer() {
     this.startTime = System.milliseconds()
  }

  @Override
  public close() {
     logger.debug(System.milliseconds() - startTime);
  }
}

class Client {
public static void main(String... args) {
   try (Metric metric = Metric.createStarted()) {
      // do stuff
   }
}
```

There are also some reasons why using lambdas is not an option here.

Comment: Whether the AutoCloseable interface and the try-with-resource pattern was intended for this or not, IMHO this is a possible use for it.

Comment: In this case, it will be more appropriate to define a Listener interface and add APIs such as metricStarted() metricStopped(). What you've presented is "Locked-in" to a single API.